Moving average for day of week in Power BI
Suppose the following scenario:
I have several measurements coming in daily from an energy company. Each measurement comes from a user and they can be in different states. I have, then, in a simplified form, a table like:



Date
State
Measurement




22/05/2024
DF
10


22/05/2024
DF
72


22/05/2024
MG
2


22/05/2024
RJ
22


15/05/2024
DF
99


15/05/2024
MG
33


15/05/2024
MG
88


08/05/2024
DF
33


08/05/2024
RJ
12


08/05/2024
RJ
77


01/05/2024
DF
88


01/05/2024
DF
1


01/05/2024
DF
32


24/04/2024
MG
22


24/04/2024
RJ
55


24/04/2024
DF
10



I want to build a Power BI where I will have slicer filters by state and I want to obtain the variation of the average of one day with the average of the measurements for the same day of the week, in the last four weeks.
So, if I have the average for May 22, which is a Wednesday, I want the average of the measurements for May 15, May 8, May 1, and April 24 (Wednesdays).
In the above example, there are some possibilities:
1 - Not selecting any state filter:
Thus, assuming for the study day 22/05, I will calculate the average for 22/05 for all measurements of all states (obtaining a single average) and calculate the average of the last 4 weeks, for the same day of the week of 22/05 for all states (obtaining a single average).
2 - Selecting one state:
The average should be calculated only for the selected state on 22/05 and the average of the last 4 weeks, for the same day of the week of 22/05 only for the selected state.
3 - Selecting more than one state:
The average should be calculated only for the selected states on 22/05 (obtaining a single average) and the average of the last 4 weeks, for the same day of the week of 22/05 only for the selected states (obtaining a single average).
The final result should be the presentation of a table like:



Date
Variation




22/05/2024
X


15/05/2024
Y


08/05/2024
Z


01/05/2024
H


24/05/2024
J



I tried everything, but I couldn't make it work at all. It seems that my filter to calculate the average of the last 4 weeks does not take the State filter into consideration.

This could be a little complex. Is there a date slicer? Do you have a Date/Calendar table? Having the table displayed as you have it requires a bit of work (to show the same day of the week for the last 4 weeks). If it was a table with the values as columns like Date | Wk 0 | Wk -1 | Wk -2 | Wk -3 | Wk -4  then it would be easier as you would create five measures.

You can create these below 3 measures and the difference of these two measures is the value you are looking for-
average_this_week = 

var this_row_date = min(your_table_name[Date])


RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_table_name[Measurement]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = this_row_date
    )
)

average_last_4_weeks = 

var this_row_date = min(your_table_name[Date])
var previous_1_week_date = this_row_date - 7
var previous_2_week_date = this_row_date - 14
var previous_3_week_date = this_row_date - 21
var previous_4_week_date = this_row_date - 28


RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_table_name[Measurement]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = previous_1_week_date
          || your_table_name[Date] = previous_2_week_date
          || your_table_name[Date] = previous_3_week_date
          || your_table_name[Date] = previous_4_week_date
    )
)

variation =  [average_this_week] - [average_last_4_weeks]

The above measures will response to your state slicer as well. Here is the sample output from your data-


I had to replace ALL with ALLSELECTED for it to work, but it finally worked. Strangely, I had already tested this several times without success, but I was creating a new column... Apparently, the measure is the best option in this case. Thank you very much!

nice to see it worked somehow :)
